# Alternate branching strategies in Gecode

Tags: c++, constraint-programming, branching-strategy, gecode

I post here to ask if there is a way to alternate different strategies of branching. Let me explain, I have an efficient branching strategy which we'll call the strategy *A*. The biggest problem is that the strategy *A* cannot be used that often. So when I cannot use the strategy *A*, I use another strategy, which I'll call the strategy *B*, which is less efficient.

The documentation says that:

> **Brancher order.** Creating a brancher registers it with its home space. A space maintains a queue of its branchers in that the brancher that is registered first is also used first for
>   branching. The first brancher in the queue of branchers is referred to as the current brancher.

So, I supposed that if I post the brancher A then the brancher *B*, the brancher *A* will has priority and each time the `status` of *A* says there is no branching to do, the brancher *B* will be used. Seems like I was wrong because when the `status` of a brancher return `false`, it is never called again. 
Here is a "*minimal example*":

```
#include <gecode/minimodel.hh>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Gecode;
using namespace std;

class MyChoice : public Choice {
  public:
    int pos; // Position of the variable
    int val; // Value of to assign

    MyChoice(const Brancher& b, int pos0, int val0)
      : Choice(b,2), pos(pos0), val(val0) {}

    // Report size occupied
    virtual size_t size(void) const {
      return sizeof(*this);
    }

    // Archive into e
    virtual void archive(Archive& e) const {
      Choice::archive(e);
      e << pos << val;
    }
};

class BranchA : public Brancher {
  protected:
    ViewArray<Int::IntView> x;
  public:
    BranchA(Home home, ViewArray<Int::IntView>& x0)
      : Brancher(home), x(x0) {}

    static void post(Home home, ViewArray<Int::IntView>& x) {
      (void) new (home) BranchA(home,x);
    }

    virtual size_t dispose(Space& home) {
      (void) Brancher::dispose(home);
      return sizeof(*this);
    }
    BranchA(Space& home, bool share, BranchA& b)
      : Brancher(home,share,b) {
      x.update(home,share,b.x);
    }
    virtual Brancher* copy(Space& home, bool share) {
      return new (home) BranchA(home,share,*this);
    }
    // status
    virtual bool status(const Space& home) const {
      for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
        if (!x[i].assigned())
          return !i%2 && x[i].in(1);
      return false;
    }
    // choice
    virtual Choice* choice(Space& home) {
      for (int i=0; true; i++)
        if (!x[i].assigned())
          return new MyChoice(*this,i,1);
      GECODE_NEVER;
      return NULL;
    }
    virtual Choice* choice(const Space&, Archive& e) {
      int pos, val;
      e >> pos >> val;
      return new MyChoice(*this, pos, val);
    }
    // commit
    virtual ExecStatus commit(Space& home, 
                              const Choice& c,
                              unsigned int a) {
      const MyChoice& pv = static_cast<const MyChoice&>(c);
      int pos=pv.pos, val=pv.val;
      if (a == 0)
        return me_failed(x[pos].eq(home,val)) ? ES_FAILED : ES_OK;
      else
        return me_failed(x[pos].nq(home,val)) ? ES_FAILED : ES_OK;
    }
};
void branchA(Home home, const IntVarArgs& x) {
  if (home.failed()) return;
  ViewArray<Int::IntView> y(home,x);
  BranchA::post(home,y);
}
// BranchB //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

class BranchB : public Brancher {
  protected:
    ViewArray<Int::IntView> x;
  public:
    BranchB(Home home, ViewArray<Int::IntView>& x0)
      : Brancher(home), x(x0) {}
    static void post(Home home, ViewArray<Int::IntView>& x) {
      (void) new (home) BranchB(home,x);
    }
    virtual size_t dispose(Space& home) {
      (void) Brancher::dispose(home);
      return sizeof(*this);
    }
    BranchB(Space& home, bool share, BranchB& b)
      : Brancher(home,share,b) {
      x.update(home,share,b.x);
    }
    virtual Brancher* copy(Space& home, bool share) {
      return new (home) BranchB(home,share,*this);
    }
    // status
    virtual bool status(const Space& home) const {
      for (int i=0; i<x.size(); i++)
        if (!x[i].assigned())
          return i%2 && x[i].in(2);
      return false;
    }
    // choice
    virtual Choice* choice(Space& home) {
      for (int i=0; true; i++)
        if (!x[i].assigned())
          return new MyChoice(*this,i,2);
      GECODE_NEVER;
      return NULL;
    }
    virtual Choice* choice(const Space&, Archive& e) {
      int pos, val;
      e >> pos >> val;
      return new MyChoice(*this, pos, val);
    }
    // commit
    virtual ExecStatus commit(Space& home, 
                              const Choice& c,
                              unsigned int a) {
      const MyChoice& pv = static_cast<const MyChoice&>(c);
      int pos=pv.pos, val=pv.val;
      if (a == 0)
        return me_failed(x[pos].eq(home,val)) ? ES_FAILED : ES_OK;
      else
        return me_failed(x[pos].nq(home,val)) ? ES_FAILED : ES_OK;
    }
};
void branchB(Home home, const IntVarArgs& x) {
  if (home.failed()) return;
  ViewArray<Int::IntView> y(home,x);
  BranchB::post(home,y);
}

// Minimal Space ///////////////////////////////////////


class TestSpace : public Space {
  protected:
    IntVarArray x;
  public:
    TestSpace(int size)
      : x(*this, size, 0, 10) {
      branchA(*this, x);
      branchB(*this, x);
    }

    TestSpace (bool share, TestSpace& s)
      : Space(share, s) {
      x.update(*this, share, s.x);
    }

    virtual Space* copy (bool share) {
      return new TestSpace(share, *this);
    }
    void print(std::ostream& os) {
      os << "x= " << x << endl;
    }
};

// Minimal Main //////////////////////:

int main (int, char**) {
  // create model and search engine
  TestSpace* m = new TestSpace(10);
  DFS<TestSpace> e(m);
  delete m;
  // search and print all solutions
  while (TestSpace* s = e.next()) {
    s->print(cout); delete s;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this example, the `status` of the brancher *A* return `true` if the next variable to assign is on an **even** index and if the variable can take the value of `1` (`false` else). And the brancher *B* `status` return `true` if the next variable to assign is on an **odd** index and if the variable can take the value of `2` (`false` else).
With that code I expected to get the solutions `[1, 2, 1, 2, ...]` and `[!1, !2, !1, !2, ...]` (and others combinations like `[!1, 2, 1, !2, ...]`) but since the branchers are disposed when their `status` return `false`, only the two first variables have been assigned.

Is there a good way to make the brancher not being disposed after its `status` return `false` (or to alternate two differents branching strategies) or should I merge the two branchers into one ?

Comment: Simply encapsulate them into one: keep separate source code, but unified control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it may help someone, here is the solution I used.
As advised by Patrick Trentin, I unified the control by making a third brancher which is a vector of branchers. Here is the implementation I used:

The header **branchAllInOne.h**:

```
#include <gecode/minimodel.hh>

using namespace Gecode;
using namespace std;

class BranchAllInOne : public Brancher {
 protected:
  // Queue of brancher (may be better with ActorLink)
  vector<Actor *> queue;

  // Every brancher are in the brancher
  BrancherGroup group;

  mutable int toChoose;

  class ChoiceAndID : public Choice {
  public:
    // Choice of the brancher used
    Choice* c;
    /// ID of brancher used
    unsigned int id;

    ChoiceAndID(const Brancher& b, Choice * c, unsigned int id);
    virtual ~ChoiceAndID();
    virtual size_t size(void) const ;
    virtual void archive(Archive& e) const ;
  };

 public:
  BranchAllInOne(Home home);
  virtual size_t dispose(Space& home);
  BranchAllInOne(Home home, bool share, BranchAllInOne& b);
  virtual ~BranchAllInOne();
  /**
   * Check status of brancher, set toChoose value to the ID of the first 
   * brancher with alternative left
   **/
  virtual bool status(const Space&) const ;

  /**
   * Let the brancher of ID toChoose make the choice
   */
  virtual Choice* choice(Space&);
  virtual Choice* choice(const Space&, Archive& e);

  /**
   * Let the brancher of ID toChoose commit his choice
   */
  virtual ExecStatus commit(Space& home, const Choice& _c, unsigned int a);

  /// Copy brancher
  virtual Actor* copy(Space& home, bool share);

  /// Post brancher
  static BranchAllInOne * post(Home home);

  virtual void print(const Space& home,
             const Choice& c,
             unsigned int a,
             ostream& o) const ;
  void pushBrancher(Space& home, Brancher *b);
};

BranchAllInOne * branchAllInOne(Home home);
```

The implementation **branchAllInOne.cpp**:

```
#include "branchAllInOne.h"

static Brancher * ActorToBrancher(Actor *a);
// Choice implementation
BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID::ChoiceAndID(const Brancher& b, Choice * c0, unsigned int id0)
  : Choice(b, c0->alternatives()),
    c(c0),
    id(id0){}

BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID::~ChoiceAndID() {
  delete c;
}

size_t BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID::size(void) const {
  return sizeof(*this) + c->size();
}

void BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID::archive(Archive& e) const {
  Choice::archive(e);
  c->archive(e);
}

BranchAllInOne::BranchAllInOne(Home home)
  : Brancher(home),
    toChoose(-1) {
  home.notice(*this,AP_DISPOSE);
}

// brancher
BranchAllInOne * BranchAllInOne::post(Home home) {
  return new (home) BranchAllInOne(home);
}


size_t BranchAllInOne::dispose(Space& home) {
  home.ignore(*this, AP_DISPOSE);
  size_t size = queue.size() * sizeof(Actor*);
  for (unsigned int i = queue.size() ; i--;) {
    size += ActorToBrancher(queue[i])->dispose(home);
  }
  queue.~vector();

  // Making sure to kill each brancher inserted in the queue (may be useless)
  group.kill(home);

  (void) Brancher::dispose(home);
  return sizeof(*this) + size;
}

BranchAllInOne::BranchAllInOne(Home home, bool share, BranchAllInOne& b)
  : Brancher(home, share, b),
    queue(b.queue.size()),
    toChoose(b.toChoose){
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < queue.size() ; i++)
    queue[i] = b.queue[i]->copy(home, share);  
}

BranchAllInOne::~BranchAllInOne() {
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < queue.size() ; i++) {
    delete queue[i];
  }
  queue.~vector();
}

Actor* BranchAllInOne::copy(Space& home, bool share){
  return new (home) BranchAllInOne(home, share, *this);
}

// status
bool BranchAllInOne::status(const Space& s) const {
  for (unsigned int i = 0 ; i < queue.size() ; i++) {
    if (ActorToBrancher(queue[i])->status(s)) {
      toChoose = i;
      return true;
    }
  }  
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return false;
}

// choice
Choice* BranchAllInOne::choice(Space& s) {
  ChoiceAndID* res = new ChoiceAndID(*this,
                                     const_cast<Choice *>(ActorToBrancher(queue[toChoose])->choice(s)),
                                     toChoose);
  toChoose = -1;
  return res;
}

Choice* BranchAllInOne::choice(const Space& s, Archive& e) {
  return new ChoiceAndID(*this,
                         const_cast<Choice *>(ActorToBrancher(queue[toChoose])->choice(s, e)),
                         toChoose);
}

// Perform commit for choice \a _c and alternative \a a
ExecStatus BranchAllInOne::commit(Space& home, const Choice& c, unsigned int a) {
  const BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID& ch =  static_cast<const BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID&>(c);
  return ActorToBrancher(queue[ch.id])->commit(home, const_cast<Choice&>(*ch.c), a);

}



void BranchAllInOne::print(const Space& home,
                           const Choice& c,
                           unsigned int a,
                           ostream& o) const {
  const BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID& ch =  static_cast<const BranchAllInOne::ChoiceAndID&>(c);
  o << ch.id << ": ";
  ActorToBrancher(queue[ch.id])->print(home, *(ch.c), a, o);
}

void BranchAllInOne::pushBrancher(Space &home, Brancher *b) {
  queue.push_back(b);
  group.move(home, *b); 
}

static Brancher * ActorToBrancher(Actor *a) {
  return dynamic_cast<Brancher *>(a);
}

// end of BranchAllInOne implementation

BranchAllInOne* branchAllInOne(Home home) {
  if (home.failed()) return NULL;
  return BranchAllInOne::post(home);
}
```

I've made some modifications to get a pointer to branchers I want to put in the vector (that include the post function of each branchers):
brancherA example:

```
BranchA * BranchA::post(Home home, ViewArray<Int::IntView>& x) {
    return new (home) BranchA(home,x);
}


BranchA * branchA(Home home, const IntVarArgs& x) {
  if (home.failed()) return NULL;
  ViewArray<Int::IntView> y(home,x);
  return BranchA::post(home,y);
}
```

The space has also been modified:

```
  TestSpace::TestSpace(int size)
    : x(*this, size, 0, 10) {
    BranchAllInOne * b = branchAllInOne(*this);
    b->pushBrancher(*this, branchA(*this, x));
    b->pushBrancher(*this, branchB(*this, x));
  }
```

I tested it with and without Gist and only got a memory leak of a pointer for each brancher put in the vector (here only two). A small problem remain is that branchers put in the vector are also scheduled after the third brancher stoped (but their status return false).